# Have & how do you use the questions on Stack Exchange in your teaching & assessment?

Tags: discussion

Can anyone share their experiences using any of the questions from Mathematics Stack Exchange in their teaching or assessment?

How do you 'save' questions for later use?

How successful have you been? What would you do differently to alter any perceived lack of success?

Thanks

Comment: This only answers the middle question:  you can "save" a question for later use by clicking on the little star below the upvote/downvote arrows.  This will "favorite" a question so that you can easily find it later.  You could also simply bookmark (using your web browser) a question (most browsers allows for hierarchical bookmark organization, so this might be quite useful).

Comment: I disagree with the meta comment; the first question, while more of an opinion question, can definitely be reframed as "give successful strategies for math education using Math.SX questions".   If the poster were asking for strategies using questions from *this* forum, it would be valid for Meta, I suppose - ?